# how to do mustache template in a pair of two

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

For instance

```
<ul id="page_{{n}}">
  <li>{{record}}</li>
  <li>{{record}}</li>
</ul>
```

so it can generated pages each having two records from the array passed.

edit

```
var record = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

document.getElementById("foliosContainer").innerHTML = Mustache.render(document.getElementById('folioTemplate').innerHTML, record);
```

Comment: Show some of your JS. what do you pass to the template?

Comment: added js code, can manipulate the record object (adding more fields to it) and the template to get desired output